# overload operator << Boost Log

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, stl

```
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& p, const std::vector<unsigned int>& vector){
  p << "[ ";
  for(auto i:vector){
    p << " "<< i << " ,";
  }
  p<< "]";
  return p;
}

#define LOG_DEBUG_MESSAGE BOOST_LOG_SEV(my_logger::get(), debug)


std::vector<unsigned int> test {1, 2, 3};
LOG_DEBUG_MESSAGE << "test "<< test;
std::cout << test  << std::endl;
```

Hello,

I overloaded my operator<< for a std::vector. When i use std::cout it works well, but with boost log i get following error:

> boost/log/utility/formatting_ostream.hpp:710:19: error: cannot bind
>   'boost::log::v2_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream::ostream_type
>   {aka std::basic_ostream}' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream&&'
>        strm.stream() << value;
>
> /opt/gcc.4.9.1/include/c++/4.9.1/ostream:602:5: note: initializing
>   argument 1 of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&
>   std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&)
>   [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; _Tp =
>   std::vector]'
>        operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __os, const _Tp& __x)

I have no idea why boost log is not working. It uses the same << operator or? On other examples with own classes it works well with overloading. I have no idea what I miss. Anyone has an idea how i can solve this error?

Comment: Boost log uses the overloaded output operator, but it probably does the overload on another class type and not `std::ostream`, which is why your code doesn't work.

Comment: As an experiment, can you try defining this `<<` operator in the std namespace and confirm if it compiles?

Comment: Maybe your traits types don't match? Try defining `operator<<` as a template `template<typename CharT, typename Traits> inline std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& p, //etc`.

Comment: bobah is correct, if you define the function in the namespace then it all works correctly. `namespace std { signature here; }` `std::ostream& std::operator<<() {}`

Answer (score 6):

'boost::log::basic_formatting_ostream  is not derived from std::ostream.

You should overload operator << for std::vector and the overloaded operator should take boost::log::formatting_ostream& as its first parameter.

Check the modified code example below:

```
inline boost::log::formatting_ostream& operator<<(boost::log::formatting_ostream& p,  std::vector<int>& vector)
{
        p << "[ ";
        for(auto i:vector){
            p << " "<< i << " ,";
        }
        p<< "]";
        return p;
}
```

Comment: Actually you can just overload std::ostream as mentioned in other posts, for instance in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32902904/properly-overload-operator-in-boost-log

Comment: However you need to get it in the *same namespace* as the data type you are overloading for, for example in the case of _point_xy_ of boost geometry:

`namespace boost {  namespace geometry { namespace model { namespace d2 {
 template<typename CT, typename CS>
 inline std::ostream & operator<< (std::ostream &os, point_xy<CT, CS> const &pt)
 {
  os << "[point_xy: " << pt.x() << ", " << pt.y() << "]";
  return os;
 }
}}}}
`

Comment: if you use `auto` then use reference as well `for (auto &i : vector) {..}` to avoid copying when vector's type is changed