# Properly overload operator << in Boost.Log

Tags: c++, boost, std, boost-log

In the [Boost.Log documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/utilities.html#log.detailed.utilities.manipulators.to_log), it is said that

> **Note**
>
> The library uses `basic_formatting_ostream` stream type for record formatting, so when customizing attribute value formatting
>   rules the `operator<<` must use `basic_formatting_ostream` instead of
>   `std::ostream`.

However, throughout the documentation, all I see is overloading `operator <<` on `std::ostream` rather than `basic_formatting_ostream` in the example code. For example, see the overload for the custom type `severity_level` [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/log/example/doc/tutorial_attributes.cpp).

According to my tests, the overloads on `std::ostream` and `basic_formatting_ostream` both worked fine. So, I'm wondering what are the advantages of overloading on one instead of the other.

Comment: The advantage of using `std::ostream` should be pretty obvious: You can use it for "normal" output as well. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no problems in overloading just `operator << (std::ostream&, ...)`, since `formatting_ostream` has

```
template< typename CharT, typename TraitsT, typename AllocatorT, typename T >
inline basic_formatting_ostream< CharT, TraitsT, AllocatorT >&
operator<< (basic_formatting_ostream< CharT, TraitsT, AllocatorT >& strm, T const& value)
{
    strm.stream() << value;
    return strm;
}
```

where `stream()` returns `std::ostream&`. If you overload `operator <<` with first arg `formatting_ostream`, than this can be used only with `boost::log`, if you overload for `std::ostream&`, then this can be used for `boost::log` and for another output.

Quote from header file:

```
 * This stream wrapper is used by the library for log record formatting. It implements the standard string stream interface
 * with a few differences:
 *
 * \li It does not derive from standard types <tt>std::basic_ostream</tt>, <tt>std::basic_ios</tt> and <tt>std::ios_base</tt>,
 *     although it tries to implement their interfaces closely. There are a few small differences, mostly regarding <tt>rdbuf</tt>
 *     and <tt>str</tt> signatures, as well as the supported insertion operator overloads. The actual wrapped stream can be accessed
 *     through the <tt>stream</tt> methods.
 * \li By default, \c bool values are formatted using alphabetical representation rather than numeric.
 * \li The stream supports writing strings of character types different from the stream character type. The stream will perform
 *     character code conversion as needed using the imbued locale.
 * \li The stream operates on an external string object rather than on the embedded one. The string can be attached or detached
 *     from the stream dynamically.
 *
 * Although <tt>basic_formatting_ostream</tt> does not derive from <tt>std::basic_ostream</tt>, users are not required to add
 * special overloads of \c operator<< for it since the stream will by default reuse the operators for <tt>std::basic_ostream</tt>.
 * However, one can define special overloads of \c operator<< for <tt>basic_formatting_ostream</tt> if a certain type needs
 * special formatting when output to log.
```

Comment: But inserting into `basic_formatting_ostream` seems to do more work than inserting into `std::ostream`. For example, see the overloaded `operator <<` that `basic_formatting_ostream` has provided for `const char*`.

Comment: @Lingxi nope, `basic_formatting_ostream` just implement interface of `basic_ostream` as close as possible.

Comment: So, the Boost.Log documentation is just outdated or what?

Comment: @Lingxi no... Probably they mean, that for just record_formatting you should write formatting_ostream, if format for log should be different from "normal" output.

Comment: `basic_formatting_ostream` doesn't do more work for output that is already supported by `std::ostream`. The wrapper either forwards the operators to the `std::ostream`-specific ones, or takes a shortcut, knowing that the output will end up in a string anyway, so, if anything, it should perform faster in those cases. The docs are correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you only overload `operator<<(std::ostream)`, it will work for every stream output, including that to `basic_formatting_ostream`. If you only overload `operator<<(basic_formatting_ostream)` it will only work for output to that type of stream.

However, you may want to **overload both**, for example, if you want to provide different or more information (such as the address of an object) to the log.