# Overloading ostream operator<< works for std::cout, but not for boost::log

Tags: c++, boost, eigen, boost-log

I've overloaded `std::ostream & operator<<` many times for different data types in the past and never had a problem. However, for some reason, the following overload for `Eigen::AlignedBox2i` does not work with `boost::log`

```
std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream & os, Eigen::AlignedBox2i const & rect )
{
  os << "foo";
  return os;
}
```

`std::cout << Eigen::AlignedBox2i();` works just fine, but `BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL( debug ) << Eigen::AlignedBox2i();` results in a number of compiler errors, starting with:

> D:\dev\ext\boost_1_80_0\boost/log/utility/formatting_ostream.hpp(929,16): error C2679: binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'T' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Any idea what is happening here?

Comment: `boost::log` is not a `std::ostream`

Comment: You are right, but the doc says "[...] the stream will by default reuse the operators for std::basic_ostream", and I've been facilitating this successfully for years now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32902904/properly-overload-operator-in-boost-log

Comment: I've done some more digging and it looks like it is designed to work with `std::ostream`.  Did you write the overloaded operator or is it provided by `Eigen`?

Comment: I wrote the overload and boiled it down to the minimal example I used in the question. Works fine with `std::cout` but not for `BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL( debug )`

Comment: I beleive the issue is that `boost::log` relies on ADL to look up the function and if this operator is not in the Eigen namespace then it will never be found.

Comment: You are right. Putting the function inside `namespace Eigen { ... }` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Your `operator<<` must be able to be found using [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) from Boost.Log namespace. For this, the operator must be defined in the namespace of one of its argument types. Given that defining new methods in `namespace std` is prohibited by the standard, you should move the operator to `namespace Eigen`.

Alternatively, you could define and use a manipulator type in your own namespace. This way you will not be affecting the Eigen library and remain compatible with it if some future Eigen version adds its own `operator<<`. For example:

```
class aligned_box_2i_manipulator
{
private:
    Eigen::AlignedBox2i const & m_rect;

public:
    explicit aligned_box_2i_manipulator(Eigen::AlignedBox2i const & rect) noexcept :
        m_rect(rect)
    {
    }

    friend std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream & os, aligned_box_2i_manipulator manip )
    {
        os << "foo";
        return os;
    }
};

inline aligned_box_2i_manipulator to_stream(Eigen::AlignedBox2i const & rect) noexcept
{
    return aligned_box_2i_manipulator(rect);
}

std::cout << to_stream(Eigen::AlignedBox2i());
```